# jquery: проблема с get

Tags: jquery, javascript, php

Код на стороне клиента

```
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    alert('11111111');
                });
                function subscribe() {

                    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
                    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
                    $.get("abc.php",
                       function(data){
                           alert(data.name);alert('0000000000000');
                         $('body').append( "Name: " + data.name ) // John
                                  .append( "Time: " + data.time ); //  2pm
                       }, "json");

                }
            </script>
```

Код на стороне сервера

```
<?php echo json_encode(array("name"=>"John","time"=>"2pm")); ?>
```

Проблема: ничего не аппендится.
Если заккоментировать append и alert(data.name), то успешно выводится 000000000.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Если вы уже успользуете jquery, то используйте везде:

    var name = $('#name').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode(array("name"=>"John","time"=>"2pm"));
?>
```

и ещё проверь в инспекторе хрома, во вкладке network что тебе приходит в ответ

Answer (score 0):

В файле abc.php после **echo json_encode(/ *....* /);** поставьте **exit();**
Я так понимаю, что данные все-таки передаваться будут, поэтому хорошо бы сделать проверку на get-запрос. Напр.:

```
if(isset($_GET['param'])){
     // обработка данных
    // и ответ
    echo json_encode(/* .... */);
    exit();
}
```

Заголовки передавать тут не надо.